# How to get the number of the current image in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7 and Views module in my site. And want show number on my current thumbnail images. Search StackoverFlow and find this code:

```
HTML CODE:
<img src="http://www.ambuvet.com/images/white-cat.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.biobest.co.uk/assets/images/diagnostics/cats.jpg" />
<img src="http://animal.discovery.com/guides/atoz/gallery/cat.jpg" />

JAVASCRIPT CODE:
window.onload = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    var image = document.images[i];
    image.setAttribute("index", i + "");
    image.onclick = function() {
        var index = this.getAttribute("index");
        alert("This is image #" + index);
    };
}
};
```

see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/uUF8x/

But i don't know, how i can replace this code for get number on the current thumbnail image. Thanks.

Comment: Always post relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link to it. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: how people will help you , if you dont say your "want" ?

Comment: What do you mean of get number? Isn't the index?

Comment: Do you want to add numbers/indexes on over thumbnails?

Comment: I've got 3 images and this image firs, even, odd on my site. And i want see number (1, 2, 3) on my images.

Comment: @Engineer yes. i want to add number on my current thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create div with thumbnails as background images like

html

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://www.ambuvet.com/images/white-cat.jpg);width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://www.biobest.co.uk/assets/images/diagnostics/cats.jpg);width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://animal.discovery.com/guides/atoz/gallery/cat.jpg);width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

js

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".thumbnail").each(function(index){
    $(this).html(index+1); // Will insert number inside div tag, use css to position it where you need
})
};​
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep Manne, can you see this code on jsfiddle? many thanks.

Comment: its usefull but i've got many columns with this classes and must seperate this class. So, i want first column: image1, image2, image3. even column: image1, image2, image3. etc...